# Electron Builder : Please specify author 'email' in the application package.json

Tags: javascript, npm, electron, electron-builder

While Generating Build Via Electron builder I am facing Following Error.

`⨯ Please specify author 'email' in the application package.json`

I also tried to add email field into package.json file.

Answer (score 1):

Under package.json file email needs to be mentioned like below.

`"author": "Author Name <author@domain.com>"`